# Return column per type in row bigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to return a row per timestamp with selected sensors, i.e.
my data is loading like this:

TIMESTAMP   SENSOR  TYPE    VALUE

2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0255
mm
731.424
2
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0212
mm
814.793
3
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0234
mm
265.607
4
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
PM1110
mm
33.7823
5
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0231
mm
1467.69
6
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0244
mm
792.808
7
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0241
mm
339.997
8
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WH0034
mm
257.325
9
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0222
mm
805.086
10
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
PM1114
mm
50.6498
11
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WH0038
mm
218.819
12
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0295
mm
175.98
13
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
PM1108
mm
46.7903
14
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0239
mm
811.464
15
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
PM1113
mm
48.81
16
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0236
mm
810.159
17
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WH0035
mm
152.784
18
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0223
mm
810.964
19
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0242
mm
1450.91
20
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WH0033
mm
295.649
21
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0245
mm
779.81
22
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
WM0259
mm
793.539
23
2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
PM1104
mm
48.5385

I want to return the values like this, where type is 'mm':

TIMESTAMP WM0212 WM0255 WM0234

2018-12-31 23:00:00 UTC x x x

The reason is, I need one row per timestamp, but my data is not coming in at the same time.

Comment: Not really the same... I want to show the separate values for each sensor, but one row per timestamp...

Comment: True - can you check the update I just did there?

Comment: I tried it. I am not really getting it to work (yet), but I just want the separate rows to work further with. You add an average per grouped answer, I don' t need that (yet)

Comment: If you don't want an `AVG` try instead `MAX` or `MIN`. If you don't want to `TRUNC` the date, then don't.